# Can multiple events have more than a 100% chance to fire?

Tags: statistics

For example, if a pitcher has a 50% chance to hit a ball, and during a game he pitches six times, what are the odds he will hit one ball?

I would assume the answer is $0.5 * 6$, or $300$%, meaning he is certain to hit $\frac{3}{6}$ balls.  However, I was told by a friend that the odds of hitting one ball is $1$ minus the odds of missing $6$ times, or $1 - 0.5^6$ which is roughly $98$%.

However, what would be the odds that he hit at least two balls, at least three balls, at least four balls, at least five balls?

If we follow the same scheme, then the odds of hitting two balls should be $1 - 0.5^6 - 0.5^5 - 0.5 - 0.5^4 - 0.5^3$ which is $26$% but this doesn't feel like the right answer.

Comment: Clearly the pitcher is not guaranteed to hit $3$ of the $6$ balls. If you flip a coin twice, do you always get one head and one tails? Your friend is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend is correct. Multiplying $2\times50\%=100\%$ implicitly assumes that the system has "memory", meaning that for example if you toss a coin and get a head, then the next toss is guaranteed to have a tail, since the probability of getting head is the same as the probability of getting tails. But that kind of reasoning is clearly absurd. What the previous toss had, has nothing to do with the current toss, provided the coin is fair and not rigged in some fashion.

Returning to your final question. The probability of hitting at *least* $2$ balls, is $1$ minus the probability of missing at least $5$ balls.

$$1 -\binom{6}{5}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^5 = 1-\frac{6}{32}=\frac{26}{32}\approx 81.25\%$$

Here $\binom{n}{r}$ is the [binomial coefficient.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)